# Join eq function not working with Jooq and Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I'm using:

- Jooq 3.13.2
- Kotlin 1.3.71
- Spring boot 2.2.6.RELESE
- Java 11

I was able to generate Jooq classes and execute a simple query:

```html
class StoryCustomRepositoryImpl @Autowired constructor(
    private val dslContext: DSLContext
): StoryCustomRepository {
    override fun findEmployeeStories(pageable: Pageable) {
        return dslContext.select(STORY.ID, STORY.DESCRIPTION)
            .from(STORY)
            .forEach { println($it[STORY.ID]) }
    }
}
```

When I try to add a bit more complex logic by adding join, compilation is failing:

```html
class StoryCustomRepositoryImpl @Autowired constructor(
    private val dslContext: DSLContext
): StoryCustomRepository {
    override fun findEmployeeStories(pageable: Pageable) {
        return dslContext.select(STORY.ID, STORY.DESCRIPTION)
            .from(STORY)
            .join(USERS).on(USERS.ID.eq(STORY.CREATED_BY))
            .forEach { println($it[STORY.ID]) }
    }
}
```

Compilation fails on following line `.join(USERS).on(USERS.ID.eq(STORY.CREATED_BY))`

Error:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public abstract fun eq(p0: Int!): Condition! defined in org.jooq.TableField
public abstract fun eq(p0: Field<Int!>!): Condition! defined in org.jooq.TableField
public abstract fun eq(p0: QuantifiedSelect<out Record1<Int!>!>!): Condition! defined in org.jooq.TableField
public abstract fun eq(p0: Select<out Record1<Int!>!>!): Condition! defined in org.jooq.TableField
```

I was following this tutorial: https://blog.jooq.org/2017/05/18/10-nice-examples-of-writing-sql-in-kotlin-with-jooq/

**Edit:**
It looks like the issue is that STORY.CREATED_BY is type of Long, while USERS.ID is type of Integer. I'm not sure what needs to be changed to be able to fix this.

Thank you

Comment: what is the generated type for the CREATED_BY field?

Comment: Hi @LiorH, as posted in edit part of the question, it looks like issue is because id was integer while created_by was biginteger in the database (resulting generated code to be integer for id and long for createdBy).

I think I found a temporary solution with using cast method:
`.leftJoin(USERS).on(USERS.ID.cast(Long::class.java).eq(STORY.CREATED_BY))`

I think better solution would be to align types in database. I think I'll end up doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably change the type of all of these `ID` columns and their reference to be the same, i.e. `BIGINT`.

As a quick workaround, you can use [`Field.coerce()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#coerce(java.lang.Class)). I would prefer that over [`Field.cast()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#cast(java.lang.Class)). The difference is that `coerce()` does not have any effect on the generated SQL (which you want to avoid to get better index usage), whereas `cast()` translates to the SQL `CAST()` function.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. Changing to coerce did the trick. I was wondering why my queries were not using indexes with cast :)